# linux mta do not forward mails to root@localhost to smart_host

Tags: sendmail, rhel7, rhel8

We are having an issue with some servers which are  forwarding mails to the smart host (exchange) for root@localhost. obviously exchange does not know localhost and therefore forwards mails to the Internet and that is giving Windows admins some headaches with archiving.

the mta of the problematic linux is sendmail.sendmail

```
There is 1 program that provides 'mta'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
*+ 1           /usr/sbin/sendmail.sendmail
```

however sendmail is not running.

how can I exclude mails sent to root or root@localhost to be forwarded to the smart host?

edit: added test emails logs

```
echo test | mailx -vvv root@localhost
Resolving host smtpp.example.com . . . done.
Connecting to x.x.x.x:smtp . . . connected.
220 XCHP12.example.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Fri, 13 Oct 2023 13:42:27 +0200
>>> HELO vmhost
250 XCHP12.example.com Hello [y.y.y.y]
>>> MAIL FROM:<root@vmhost>
250 2.1.0 Sender OK
>>> RCPT TO:<root@localhost>
250 2.1.5 Recipient OK
>>> DATA
354 Start mail input; end with <CRLF>.<CRLF>
>>> .
250 2.6.0 <65292d1e.BMLW6UWNjXjY0mTp%root@vmhost> [InternalId=168414257611320, Hostname=XCHP21.example.com] 1553 bytes in 0.141, 10,729 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery
>>> QUIT
221 2.0.0 Service closing transmission channel
```

nothing is written to /var/log/maillog

i would expect that root@localhost is delivered locally to /var/mail/spool/root per instance.

if i try to deliver to only 'root' i don't get any email at all

```
echo test | mailx -vvv root
Resolving host smtpp.example.com . . . done.
Connecting to x.x.x.x:smtp . . . connected.
220  Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Fri, 13 Oct 2023 13:49:06 +0200
>>> HELO vmhost
250 EXCHP12.example.com Hello [y.y.y.y]
>>> MAIL FROM:<root@vmhost>
250 2.1.0 Sender OK
>>> RCPT TO:<root>
501 5.1.3 Invalid address
smtp-server: 501 5.1.3 Invalid address
"/root/dead.letter" 10/259
. . . message not sent.
```

the problem is that the smarthost does not know what to do with a mail for @localhost so it send it to the Internet and it causes unnecessary noise.

Comment: Could you provide *ALL* log entries generated by such email message on the sending host? [There are many possible configurations causing it. It would help to narrow down possibilities]

Comment: I added the logs from the tests i have performed.

Comment: It does not look like standard (newer) sendmail installation.  Such installation should relay message to local sendmail daemon listening on loopback (127.0.0.1). What is reported by 1. `/usr/sbin/sendmail -Ac -d60.5 -bv root` 2. `grep -E '^D. ' /etc/mail/sendmail.cf`

Comment: 1.  `/usr/sbin/sendmail -Ac -d60.5 -bv root
Notice: -bv may give misleading output for non-privileged user
map_lookup(dequote, root, %0=root) => NOT FOUND (0)
map_lookup(dequote, root, %0=root) => NOT FOUND (0)
map_lookup(dequote, root, %0=root) => NOT FOUND (0)
root... deliverable: mailer relay, host [smtpp.example.com], user root@vmhost.example.com`

2.  return nothing.

Comment: 3. Do you have `*.cf `files in '/etc/mail/' other than `sendmail.cf`? 4. What is reported by `grep -nE '^D' /etc/mail/*.cf`? [Sorry, I know sendmail but I have to guess your non standard configuration from a few+ possibilities]

Comment: no problems. thank you for your assistance. 
here is the output: 
`/root: grep -nE '^D' /etc/mail/*.cf
/etc/mail/sendmail.cf:104:DS
/etc/mail/sendmail.cf:151:DnMAILER-DAEMON
/etc/mail/sendmail.cf:166:DZ8.15.2
/etc/mail/submit.cf:72:DS
/etc/mail/submit.cf:112:DnMAILER-DAEMON
/etc/mail/submit.cf:115:D{MTAHost}[smtpp.example.com]
/etc/mail/submit.cf:119:DZ8.15.2/Submit`

how is sendmail even involved. the service is disabled

Comment: Final query I hope: `echo '$j' | /usr/sbin/sendmail -bt -Ac`

Comment: sorry i was out for the wekend: 
`echo '$j' | /usr/sbin/sendmail -bt -Ac
ADDRESS TEST MODE (ruleset 3 NOT automatically invoked)
Enter <ruleset> <address>
> vmhost.example.com `

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:** (as detected by extra info provided in the comments)
Your configuration uses `submit.cf` to relay **ALL** messages to remote SMTP server.  By default `submit.cf` would relay messages to local sendmail daemon listening on 127.0.0.1.

**Suggested fix:**
Use normal/standard submit.cf and configure sendmail.cf to use smart host.
Messages to all local mailboxes/addresses are not relayed via smart host.
Such relay requires other configuration means.

Comment: where can i find a default/standard submit.cf?  and how would I configure sendmail